# How to redirect in nginx to index file

Tags: nginx

I have simple example:

```
   location / {
        rewrite  ^/$  /index.html  last;
        root /test/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

How ti redirect "/" to /index.html ?.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following directive to your config (and removing the rewrite)

```
index index.html;
```

will tell nginx to use index.html for any directory, 
see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index for details

though given the fastcgi bit you probably want index.php instead?

usually you also want to move the root to your server block instead of in the location block  (so as not to have to repeat yourself in each location block)